# The random variable X

Tags: probability, density-function

The random variable X has density function
$$f(x)=(K+1)x^2 $$

```
             .
```

$K$ is constant. What is the value of $K$? and find the expected value of $E(x)$.

Comment: What have you tried?  And what is the domain of $x$?

Comment: The domain is      0<x<1

Comment: I found the value of K=255

Comment: How?????  Please show your work in the problem.

Comment: I'm Sorry Mr.David I made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Set

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^1 (k+1) x^2\ dx = 1$$

to find $k = 2$.

Then $${\cal E}[x] = \int\limits_{x=0}^1 x\ 3 x^2\ dx = \frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: What is the purpose of answering the question, rephunting? The asker evidently don't want to learn and just want to get an answer.

Comment: Kludg What makes say that.. ?